# How to specify return type of class constructor (e.g. using proxy)?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm pretty new to the Typescript world. Trying around with it a little more I stumbled across a problem when using a `Proxy` as a returned value from a class constructor.

Imagine the following code:

```
class Container {
  constructor() {
    return new Proxy(this, containerProxyHandler);
  }
}

const container = new Container();

container.sessionStorage = () => {
  return new SessionStorage('SESSION_ID');
};

container.session = factory(() => {
  return new Session(container.sessionStorage);
});

container.random = protected(() => {
  return Math.random();
});
```

The `Container` type is intended to be used as a dependency injection container. So assigning the properties inside the `Container` class is not possible due to the variable amount of services it will store.

When validated it complains about missing properties `sessionStorage`, `session` and `random` inside the `Container` type when assigning arrow functions to them.

```
Property 'sessionStorage' does not exist on type 'Container'
```

I could of course assign a type to the container variable myself via `as` or use a factory function, but find this approaches cumbersome for other people to use for example in case of library.

```
const container = new Container() as { [key: string]: any };
```

Is there an easier solution for this without the need of extra boilerplate code?

Comment: Instead of `container.sessionStorage = ()`, try `public static sessionStorage = () =>` inside class

Comment: The container is intended to have a variable amount of properties, similar to an object. So defining the property inside the `Container` is not really possible or feasible.

Comment: *Property 'sessionStorage' does not exist on type 'Container'* is a TS error. Its because, you are trying to add a property that is not in the type. One hack could be `const key="sessionStorage"; new Session(container[key])`

Comment: Also point of TS is to have pre-defined set of keys. If the key will be part of some objects but not all, make it optional. But defining on the fly keys is just wasting TS

Comment: So you would recommend to not use TS when ever a library uses an object with a variable amount of properties? That sounds pretty limiting to me.

Comment: *So you would recommend to not use TS*, No. I suggest to create a type with all possible keys. You can make properties as optional if they are not meant to be a part of all objects. TS is meant so that we can have staticly typed objects. If you want to add dynamically typed objects to TS and then convert your code to JS, why not directly use JS. But if you are using TS, its always better to have optional properties than having type as `any`

Comment: Imagine other people are using this `Container` type in their own project. The only way for them to use the `Container` is by creating an own container class extending the one I provided and adding the service properties, he or she wants to have. Thats even more cumbersome than using the `as` operator as for example @RaxWeber suggested, don't you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150780/discussion-between-rajesh-and-johnny).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an interface for it:

```
interface SomeType { 
  [name: string]: any; 
}
```

Comment: He said that it is intended to a variable amount of properties, which is similar to that of a JS object. Why ask me if he's the one who wants it like that?

Comment: *Why ask me*, because you chose to answer. As knowledged person, we should help in showing the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the effort @RaxWeber. Already thought about this. My question is about how to not need an `any` type at all, because I was able to somehow define the type of the returned value from the class constructor (or similar).

Comment: Using an interface works perfectly. Though I think @Rajesh is right pointing out that TS might not be a good fit for having a typed system when using a flexible container. Maybe extending the `Container` type is–at the end– more feasible.